# Does the level of DLC missions adjust to my current level?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have been playing Bordelands 2 for the last 2 weeks, and I am now at lvl 28 and almost finished the main story line. I also bought the season pass together with the game, and they are downloaded already to my console.

At this point I had a lot of stuff on my radar, I have a few new side missions, there is the main story to finish, and there are the DLC's.

Today I thought before going on with the normal game, let me check out the dlc's, so I accepted the first missions. Later on I decided to finish the main story first, and then have some fun with the DLC's, because they look pretty cool.

Now my main question is this. I started the DLC's and it says that they are lvl 26-28, did I just screw that up. Maybe when I come back to the dlc's I will be close to lvl 40, but the missions in the dlc's are lvl 28, that won't be any fun.

Will the lvl of the dlc mission adjust to my lvl, or did I just cap it at 28.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you take a mission the level *for that mission* is set in stone. However all missions after that mission and missions you haven't taken yet will continue to scale as high as they're set to scale. [See this answer for DLC level ranges in playthrough 1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/101772/11920); most max around 30. In playthrough 2 the DLCs will max at 50, which is also your max level. Since you're already at the end of the main storyline you'll probably just want to start playthrough 2 before doing the DLCs.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the second playthtough. I googled it and it sounds pretty cool.

Comment: @SaifBechan in that case see also http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work

Comment: I am 50 and have started playthrough 2.5 and had already been to Oasis at around level 45. So far everything is still at level 45, even new quests. Has the DLC locked in at level 45 or something?

Comment: ok as soon as I completed the next Main pirate quest, which had been in my quest log at ~45, then everything shot up to 50.

Answer (score 0):

If you start out the mission level 26 or whatever you will end up fighting the dlc eneimes at that level or what ever level its ranged but all dlcs have a set level for you to do they are 15 for Pirate 15 for Tourge 32 for Tiny Tina and endgame+ for Hammerlock.

Answer (score -1):

In normal mode you can start the docs to your lvl at level 15 to 30 accept tiny Tina's assault on dragon keep and hammerlocks big game hunt which is level 32 to 35.

In UVHM (ultimate valt hunter mode) you can start a doc that you want to be your level from level 35 to 50. It's your choice if you want awesome loot in the begining of the game or awesome loot at the ending of the game so you can pass through you're next game mode with ease.

When you get to UVHM (Ultimate Valt Hunter Mode) you have to choose wisely with your docs because you want the good loot. I recommend starting the dlcs that have guns that you want that are in onley the dlcs. You should start that dlc at lvl 72 if you have all the level caps so you can wreak people when farming and you can use those great guns from your patience for OP levels.

I played every characters playthrough on borderlands 2 all the way up to UVHM and OP8 which is the highest OP level and I finished all the characters on borderlands 1 and borderlands the pre sequel.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.