# From what DLC should I start?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just finished the main storyline in BL2. I'm level 35, from what DLC can I continue my adventure? Or does it even matter?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/101772/4797), in Normal Mode (first Playthrough), the enemy levels for the DLCs are:

> - Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty - levels 15 to 30
> - Mr.  Torgue's Campaign of Carnage - levels 15 to 30
> - Sir Hammerlock's Big    Game Hunt - levels 30 to 35
> - Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep - levels 30 to 35

In True Vault Hunter Mode (TVHM), enemy levels in the DLCs will scale to around the player's level starting from around their Normal Mode playthrough level caps until level 50.

In Ultimate True Vault Hunter Mode (UTVHM), enemy levels in the DLCs will scale to around the player's level starting from around level 50 until level 61.

Since you're already at level 35 (and have already hit the level cap for the DLCs), you might want to play *any* DLC on True Vault Hunter Mode instead, so [enemies will scale to around your level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/89690/4797).

Comment: Will I have to pass the game on "True Vault Hunter Mode" To play the DLC's?

Comment: You don't need to. At the beginning of True Vault Hunter mode, you can fast travel to the DLC locations using the Fast Travel station at Claptrap's Place, Windshear Waste (first place you encounter in the game).

Comment: New DLC for Tiny Tina.  What enemy levels are there?

Comment: @DavidStarkey [It seems to be the same as Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt: levels 30 to 35](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/1h3o63/what_are_the_enemy_level_ranges_for_each/caqjrpg).