# Where to farm after killing the final boss?

Tags: borderlands-2

I killed the warrior and jack in my first play-through. Now I'm wanting to get to a higher level before TVHM and I'm wondering where to farm. The warrior is dead and I don think I can get back there to make him spawn again. Need gear and exp, I'm level 30 siren with no dlc although I'm not opposed to getting it.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely can walk to any boss in the game and farm them again. If you are comfortable with **Hero's Pass** and **The Warrior**, go for it (all the rest are lower level on Normal anyway).

If you are not opposed to getting DLC, I'd say go for it - playing new content is always more interesting than farming old places. Some DLC ([see this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/101763)) is explicitly designed to be played after the main quest, and level up to 35.

Being 33 is perfecly fine to start TVHM at - if you go with farming, do not press yourself too hard.

By the way, Borderlands 2 Game of the Year Edition is [coming next week](http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/08/28/borderlands-2-game-of-the-year-edition-confirmed) - it may be a better deal considering DLCs. Or not :-)

Comment: Okay cool! ALso i dont think ill buy the goty, maybe just seasons pass.

Comment: If you decide to wait on that DLC, the warrior is good for about 14,000 xp per kill from 30 to 33 and 12,000xp from 33 to 36, so you can level up pretty fast by just killing him and then save and exit. when you re-enter the game you will be in the zone again and able to kill him again. rinse repeat. Also, he usually drops like 12 to 16 eridium per kill so that is handy...

Comment: Where should i go after 36? TVHM or keep farming till 41, because ive heard of people doing that

Comment: @user56626 I do not really see a point of farming till 41. Start of TVHM is doable at 30, comfortable at 33 and yao-ming-easy at 36. If you run into trouble later in TVHM, it is better to farm there anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Also the Bunker is a great farm.

Comment: Why is this a good farming spot?  We want answers that provide details, not just a location.  Please expand your answer to include more information.

Comment: It has dropped orange weapons and it gives you about 10 eridium each time that you kill him and also It can give you a head for your character!

Comment: I'd recommend adding that to your answer.